# How to Avoid update deadlock

Tags: multithreading, postgresql, jdbc, sql-update, deadlock

While working on JDBC with Postgres...

**Isolationlevel="Read committed"**

I got the same deadlock in a multithreaded environment when I tried updating the table after some operations.
So I tried using multiple queries as shown below

```
  ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE TableA SET column1=column1-? WHERE column2=? and column3=?;"  
                          + "UPDATE TableA SET column1=column1+? WHERE column2=? and column3=?;");
```

Here are the postgresql logs for the error

```
2016-12-19 12:25:44 IST STATEMENT:  UPDATE TableA SET column1=column1+$1 WHERE column2=$2 and column3=$3
2016-12-19 12:25:44 IST FATAL:  connection to client lost
2016-12-19 12:25:45 IST ERROR:  deadlock detected
2016-12-19 12:25:45 IST DETAIL:  Process 8524 waits for ShareLock on transaction 84942; blocked by process 12520.
    Process 12520 waits for ShareLock on transaction 84940; blocked by process 20892.
    Process 20892 waits for ExclusiveLock on tuple (1,5) of relation 25911 of database 24736; blocked by process 8524.
    Process 8524: UPDATE TableA SET column1=column1-$1 WHERE column2=$2 and column3=$3
    Process 12520: UPDATE TableA SET column1=column1-$1 WHERE column2=$2 and column3=$3
    Process 20892: UPDATE TableA SET column1=column1-$1 WHERE column2=$2 and column3=$3
2016-12-19 12:25:45 IST HINT:  See server log for query details.
2016-12-19 12:25:45 IST CONTEXT:  while locking tuple (1,12) in relation "TableA"
2016-12-19 12:25:45 IST STATEMENT:  UPDATE TableA SET column1=column1-$1 WHERE column2=$2 and column3=$3
2016-12-19 12:25:45 IST LOG:  could not send data to client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

In this multithreaded environment, I was expecting TableA's rows to get locked for the 2 statements and avoid deadlock.

I see similar scenario explained in 
[Postgres Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html)

I could not find any method to avoid this kind of deadlock. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

P.S: Autocommit is set FALSE already and tried using preparedStatements with single UPDATE query.

**Regarding multiple queries** ->  [Multiple queries in one Preparedstatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement) and [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/art/wiki/Multiple%20Statements/) shows that postgres doesnt need any additional configurations.

Comment: Updates don't lock the whole table, only the row in question. From the docs you linked: `The best defense against deadlocks is generally to avoid them by being certain that all applications using a database acquire locks on multiple objects in a consistent order`.

Comment: how do you prepare two `UPDATE` statements?..

Comment: Sorry, my mistake @NickBarnes.  I meant rows only.
I need to update two rows in that table in a multithreaded environment. How can I prevent deadlock in such situation and achieve the functionality?

Comment: @VaoTsun I am using jdbc.. mentioned my prepared statement with SQL in description. It works fine normally, In multithreaded it gives deadlock. Multiple queries are allowed in Postgres by default.

Comment: @Elnino: Like the docs say, use a consistent order, e.g. make sure that the first row updated is always the one with the smallest ID.

Comment: @NickBarnes Yes that may avoid deadlock for some scenarios. But they sure do encounter at some point(which will be a catastrophe for the product). This my friend is for a ledger. Can't take risks on Money.

Comment: @Elnino if you use two updates in one `prepareStatement`, you should provide correct answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366164/can-i-use-multiple-statements-in-a-jdbc-prepared-query - people need to know how it works in fact

Comment: @VaoTsun Sorry, [Multiple queries in one Preparedstatement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement) and https://sourceforge.net/p/art/wiki/Multiple%20Statements/ this shows that postgres doesnt need any additional configurations.

Comment: @Elnino: A consistent lock ordering will prevent deadlock in **all** scenarios, as long as all processes adhere to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Nick Barnes quoted in comment from the link I shared.

> The best defense against deadlocks is generally to avoid them by being
>   certain that all applications using a database acquire locks on
>   multiple objects in a **consistent order**.

Especially for update deadlocks as mentioned, the order of update leads to deadlock.

**Example**:

```
UPDATE Table SET ... WHERE id= 1;
UPDATE Table SET ... WHERE id= 2;
```

and

```
UPDATE Table SET ... WHERE id= 2;
UPDATE Table SET ... WHERE id= 1;
```

The general solution is to **order the updates** based on id. This is what the consistent order meant.

I didn't understand that till I struggle with this deadlock.

Answer (score 2):

By my experience deadlock in PostgreSQL most likely happens in "real life" when you "cross" updates in 2 long running transactions. (explanation follows). And it is quite hard to even simulate deadlock on PG. Here is an example - http://postgresql.freeideas.cz/simulate-deadlock-postgresql/
So classical deadlock means:

- You start transaction 1 + do update on row 1. Your procedure continues but transaction 1 is still opened and not commited.
- Then you start transaction 2 + do update on row 2. Procedure continues but transaction 2 is still opened and not commited.
- Now you try to update row 2 from transaction 1 which causes this operation to wait.
- Now you try to update row 1 from transaction 2 - in this moment PG reports deadlock and ends this transaction.

So I recommend you to commit transactions as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in real life we can't autoCommit. I need to rollback in case the second update or the later fails.

Comment: I understand it and I said nothing about "autoCommit". But if you have heavily multi threaded environment and you leave transactions opened for a relatively long time then deadlocks are very probable to happen. This is how transactions work.